# Uploading a project at the expo, changing the version

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am trying to make a version update for my application

I changed the version to 8 and even though I do npx eas build -p android it still remains the same version 7

```
  "expo": {
    "name": "test",
    "slug": "test",
    "version": "8.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/logo.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "black"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "android": {
      "versionCode": 8,
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },

      "package": "AwesomeProjectMazlot"
    },

    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "yourappname",
      "buildNumber": "8.0.0"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "4fa9fe0a63"
      }
    },
    "runtimeVersion": {
      "policy": "sdkVersion"
    },
    "updates": {
      "url": "https://u"
    }
  }
}
```

How can this be fixed?

Thanks

I tried to update...